# How can I make multiple resolutions of the same image available depending on a radio button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a ToolStrip with several ToolStripButtons in it that all contain bitmaps. I want to be able to drag a copy of the image onto a Drawing Panel I have set up, however I want to be able to choose from small, medium, or large file sizes (32x32, 64x64, 128x128). I've got three radio buttons set up with the corresponding sizes. Initially I was thinking of having the three image files in an ImageList and then hook that up with the tsButton they relate to, however 1) I couldn't figure out how to setup an ImageList with ToolStripButtons only regular Buttons seem possible.. and 2) This will be an extreme amount of work for the 50 or so ToolStripButtons I'll have by the end.

I'm looking for a better solution and I'm open to ideas. I'm thinking of opening the image from file using a predefined string such as "C:\bitmaps\theimageLarge.png" where I concatenate a string relating to the size (ie. Small, Medium, or Large) with the original image location, and then add an appropriate extension on the end. However I believe opening files that way is only possible in imageLists... which brings me back to #2 and the issue of having 50+ ImageList's with 3 different resolutions of the same image in each of the ImageList's.

Any and all suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Share some of your code and we will help you get to a solution.

Comment: I'm not so much looking for code correction but design implementation help, I mainly want to know if it's possible and if there's an easier way than the way I've stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

**My Goal:** I wanted my "Diagrams" which are actually ToolStripButtons to be able to dynamically determine their size by the set of radio buttons on the right (Small, Medium & Large).

[image: Initial Situation]

**What I did:** Universally agreed upon a naming convention and gave all the ToolStripButtons the appropriate "Text" property relating to their button, which was simply "uturn", "stop", "construction", etc. I also filled in the "Text" property on each of my RadioButtons giving them "Small", "Medium", and "Large" respectably.

All RadioButtons had the same EventHandler for OnClick which would simply change the value of a size String I declared in the MainForm of my application.

I then had an event handler to handle the MouseDown Event of all the ToolStripButtons, inside that this is what the code looked like.

```
        ToolStripButton thisButton = (ToolStripButton)sender;
        var temp = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(thisButton.Text + size);
        thisButton.DoDragDrop((Image)temp, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

My resources folder had three different files for each Diagram. "stopSmall", "stopMedium", "stopLarge" and so on.